# How to call a function inside a ItemTemplate at a ListView Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ListView Control and need to insert some pictures in the ItemTemplate.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="VareListView">
 <LayoutTemplate>
   <table cellpadding="2" runat="server" id="tblVarer" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;" >
    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder">
    </tr>
</table>
 </LayoutTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
    <tr id="Tr1" style="height:100px" class="tblRow" runat="server" >
   <td valign="top">
     <asp:Image ID="ProduktImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("images_produkt/{0}.jpg",Eval("Varenr"))%>'  />
   </td>
   <td valign="top" class="">
         <asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Varenavn1")%>' />
         <br />
         <asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("Varenr: {0}",Eval("Varenr")) %>' />
         <br />
         <asp:Label ID="Varenavn2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Varenavn2") %>' />
         <br />
         <asp:Label ID="Varenavn3" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Varenavn3") %>' />
         <br />
```

at this point I need to insert pictures if a filename contains "Varenr"
Something like this

```
        DirectoryInfo myDir = new DirectoryInfo(Request.PhysicalPath.Substring(0,               Request.PhysicalPath.LastIndexOf("\\")) + "/images_produkt/montering"); 
        FileInfo[] files = myDir.GetFiles(varenr + "*");
        if (files.Length != 0)
        {
            foreach (FileInfo fil in files)
            {
                            Image img = new Image();
                            img.ImageUrl = "/images_produkt/montering/" + fil.Name;
                            img.Height = 20;
                            img.Width = 20;
            }
          }
```

But I downt now how to get this to work :)
the rest of the ListView code is like this

```
   </td>
   <td valign="top" align="right" class="">
         <asp:Panel ID="Enhet" runat="server" Visible='<%#Eval("Enhet").ToString() != String.Empty %>'>
             <asp:Label ID="Pris" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0} kr",Eval("Pris2"))%>' />
             <br />
         </asp:Panel>
         <asp:Label ID="Vekt" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Format("{0} Kg",Eval("Vekt"))%>' />
         <br />
         <asp:TextBox ID="Antall" runat="server" Text="1" Width="20"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='style/shoping01.jpg' Width="22" Height="22" />
   </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ItemDataBound event and place a PlaceHolder control where you want your images to get inserted, in your ItemDataBound event find the Placeholder control and add your images dynamically, your code behind should like this.

```
protected void yourdatalist_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    var placeHolder = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("YourPlaceholderIdHere")

    //do what you want
    placeHolder.Controls.Add(your images)
}
```

I have not tested that but hopefully can give you and idea.

If you want more control over the Html you can nest a DataList and assing it a Datasource

e.g.

```
 <asp:DataList ID="nestedImages" runat="server" 
        DataSource="<%# GetDataSourceForImages(((ListViewItem)Container).DataItem) %>" >
   <ItemTemplate> 
         your html here
   </ItemTemplate>
```

GetDataSourceForImages is a protected method that do what you want and return a list that will be used as datasource, you have to refine this of course.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the ItemDataBound event from your ListView control. In the event handler, examine the data item, and modify the content appropriately.