# asp.net repeater item template <li> element, how to set any attribute through a function?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, repeater

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptStockListings">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <li rank=$.getRank(<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>,           <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"IsPremium") %>))
```

This doesn't execute the getRank(index, isPremium) function that i have in separate JS file which returns me a string.

And the output looks like:
getRank(1,true) instead of return value of the function.

How can i call function from here? I need to call it since i have to use global variable defined in that js file.

Comment: You can't call a Javascript function from code nuggets.

Comment: What do i do then, i have to do this, access that js global parameter to set this li rank attribute.

Comment: You add some JS code so that when the page loads there is a "each" call on the li to set the rank to what you want. Alternatively, in the code behind you could run some code that sets the rank there for another idea here.

Comment: Can i access that global variable here somehow?

Comment: @sahil - Can't help until you provide proper requirement, what you are trying to do and show some more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call code-behind functions from inside a repeater. (search for this if you can use code-behind.)

sample: [How to call a function inside a ItemTemplate at a ListView Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127387/how-to-call-a-function-inside-a-itemtemplate-at-a-listview-control)

i had another example but i can't find it now. hth.